# MVC API controller's complex object not getting populated from jquery ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call a POST API controller. The controller gets called but the complex object comes in empty. I have ran Fiddler and the object is even coming through populated there. What am I doing wrong?

***My C# object***

```
public class RegisterUser
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Business { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

***API Post Controller***

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(RegisterUser user)
{
   //This is where the problem is. Everything in user is null 
   //even though I can see it coming through on Fiddler.
}
```

***Javascript code***

```
function User(personId, userName, email, business, employeeNumber) {
   this.PersonId = personId;
   this.Email = email;
   this.Business = business;
   this.EmployeeNumber = employeeNumber;
   this.UserName = userName;
}

function RegisterUser(url) {
   var createdUser = new User("b3fd25ba-49e8-4247-9f23-a6bb90a62691", "username", "email", "business", "56465");
   $.ajax(url, {
       data: JSON.stringify({ user: createdUser }),
       type: "post",
       contentType: "application/json"
  });
}
```

***Web API Route Config***

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RegisterApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{user}"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The AJAX call is asynchronous and it looks like you're executing the resulting code before any data is returned.

Comment: The problem is the API controller RegisterUser object is not being populated...The js ajax doesn't even have a return yet.

Comment: Do you have the HttpPost attribute on the action?

Comment: It is a mvc web api controller. You don't have to specify anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createdUser` already contains the data needed by Web.Api in the correct format there is no need to wrap it inside an `user` property which confuses the model binder.

Just write `data: JSON.stringify(createdUser)` and it should work fine:

```
function RegisterUser(url) {
   var createdUser = new User("b3fd25ba-49e8-4247-9f23-a6bb90a62691", "username", "email", "business", "56465");
   $.ajax(url, {
       data: JSON.stringify(createdUser),
       type: "post",
       contentType: "application/json"
  });
}
```

The principles of the model binding are simple until you have matching property names and object structure in your JS and C# objects and it should work fine.